# Redirect a url containing an anchor (#)

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, anchor

There is a URL：https://www.carpark.cc/contact_us.html#b
that I want to redirect to：
https://www.carparkpro.com/contact-us/#hk

My .htaccess code is：

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^cn\.carpark\.cc$
RewriteRule ^contact_us/(.*)/? https://www.carparkpro.com/contact-us/#cn$ [NC,NE,R=301]
```

but it didn't work， pls tell me how to write the code， thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect the actual URL that get's requested is `https://www.carparkpro.com/contact-us`, not `https://www.carparkpro.com/contact-us/` which explains why the rule does not get applied. Please understand that anchors (`...#...`) are *not* part of the URL. A client will *never* send that anchor, but only the URL. So the server will never receive such an anchor.

I would suggest a slightly modified version of your rule:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^cn\.carpark\.cc$
RewriteRule ^/?contact_us/? https://www.carparkpro.com/contact-us/#cn$ [NC,R=301,L]
```

Comment: thanks your answer, but I still had one question, if the origin url have a anchors like：https://www.carpark.cc/release.html#b  。And the new url is：https://www.carparkpro.com/offer-hk/  。  In this case ，how to write the code made the new link won't appear anchors# ？  By using your code ，the new url will become：https://www.carparkpro.com/offer-hk/#b

Comment: That is strange, I have never seen something like that. And quite frankly I can't imagine how this should happen... As said the server never sees such an anchor, so where should it take the information from? Could it be that you are looking at some cached results in your client?

Comment: Actually I had already clean the cached in my client，  cn.carpark.cc/morelease.html#b => www.carparkpro.com/offer-mo/        But it also become： www.carparkpro.com/offer-mo/#b

Comment: Ah OK. Then I assume that this is what your client does, nothing the server is responsible for. You can check yourself: open the browsers console, check the networking tab in there and make a test request to mentioned URL. You should see 1. the redirection coming in (to what URL?) and 2. that URL getting requested again.